# Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type

Tags: kotlin

## Problem

I'm checking for null, but receiving this error:

```
// testNullCheck.kt
fun isNullOrEmpty(list: List<Int>?): Boolean {
  if (list.isEmpty() || list == null ) {
    return true
  }else {
    return false
  } 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val test: Boolean = isNullOrEmpty(
    listOf<Int>()
  )
  println(test)
}
```

Compilation output:

```sh
leetcode/kotlin [master●] » kotlinr testNullCheck.kt
Compiling, please wait...
testNullCheck.kt:2:11: error: only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (fg.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type List<Int>?
  if (list.isEmpty() || list == null ) {
          ^
1
2
```

### Questions:

- Why is the compiler complaining?
- Does the order of if-statement operands matter?

Answer (score 2):

When you combine conditionals, they are evaluated from left to right. So you have to check for null first before calling `isEmpty()` on it:

```
fun isNullOrEmpty(list: List<Int>?): Boolean {
  if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
    return true
  }else {
    return false
  } 
}
```

Note, the if-statement is redundant. Just do this:

```
fun isNullOrEmpty(list: List<Int>?): Boolean {
  return list == null || list.isEmpty()
}
```

I changed your function name because it was inconsistent with what you're checking.

Also, there already is a built-in function you can call on nullable lists:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val list: List<Any>? = null
  val test1: Boolean = list.isNullOrEmpty()
  println(test1)
}
```

Comment: It's not just that the left-hand operand is evaluated _first_ for `&&` and `||`; it's that they short-circuit.  This means that if the first operand fixes the result (i.e. false for `&&`, or true for `||`) then the second operand won't be evaluated _at all_.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm checking for null. Why is the compiler complaining?

## Answer

you call isEmpty() on something that could be null. You must check whether it's null before you call a function on an object. Kotlin does this to avoid `NullPointerException`s

```
// testNullCheck.kt
fun isNullOrEmpty(list: List<Int>?): Boolean {
  if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
    return true
  }else {
    return false
  } 
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val test: Boolean = isNullOrEmpty(
    listOf<Int>()
  )
  println(test)
}
```

Compilation output:

```
leetcode/kotlin [master●] » kotlinr testNullCheck.kt
Compiling, please wait...
true
```